# Ubuntu 20.04 won’t boot

Tags: 20.04

Recently, I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04. And after it got installed, I restarted my laptop, and it wouldn’t boot. It just brings me to the boot options and when I select one of them, it will just stay on the booting screen forever.

Comment: In the same boat with you here. Got any fix?